Green and purple flickering screen on a Thinkpad P51 running Ubuntu 24.04
I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P51 running Ubuntu 24.04 (Mate desktop environment), with all packages updated (apt dist-upgrade ran yesterday, August 18th 2024).
Today I booted up the machine and found the screen flickering with horizontal graded bands in green, gray, and purple colors (GIF below):

While exploring solutions, I used the NVidia settings indicator in the panel to switch to "Intel" graphics, and rebooted the machine. This indicator usually has three options, something like "Intel (power save)", "NVidia (performance)", and "on-demand"
This did not fix the problem, but it did unexpectedly cause the NVidia settings to disappear from the indicator panel applet, hinting that perhaps there is at least something wrong with the software configuration.
The machine was fine the day before, and there was no mechanical disturbance overnight. But, I suppose sometimes hardware just fails.
It is hard to relate this issue to past questions as clear videos are only sometimes provided. The closest I could find is this question, which is not a perfect match—but was in the end a software fault.
Steps taken so far

The NVidia chipset in question is GM206GLM [Quadro M2200 Mobile].
To rule out that apt dist-upgrade broke the NVidia drivers, I ran sudo apt-get purge nvidia-* and rebooted. The machine now uses the nouveau driver.
I've hooked up a second monitor and this seems to be running normally (it was not working using the NVidia driver).
The problem on the main screen persists but is now intermittent; The laptop usually runs with a normal display for a few minutes after every reboot.

This feels like a hardware fault to me, but there are occasional reports of software changes resolving behavior like this. I also can't find evidence of any other laptop from this line failing this way, which makes me suspect it may yet be a software issue.
What further steps would I take to confirm with greater confidence that this as a hardware fault?
Edit 1:
Here is the output of inxi -G after rebooting and using the GRUB menu to select kernel 6.5.0-45-generic rather than 6.8.0-40-generic (which was in use before):
:
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics P630 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM206GLM [Quadro M2200 Mobile] driver: nouveau v: kernel
  Device-3: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915,nouveau resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz
    2: 1920x1080
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics P630 (KBL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2

The problem has not returned yet running kernel 6.5.0-45-generic so I suppose there must be something broken in 6.8.0-40-generic?

Thanks @kanehekili, the issue seems to be present in kernel 6.8.0-40-generic with both the nouveau and nvidia drivers. So far it has not returned if I boot into 6.5.0-45-generic instead, but it may yet return (it is intermittent). I suppose I can boot this kernel until the issue is resolved ( :

Since it worked, I created an answer for others to see

An update of your kernel might lead to inconsistencies with the NVIDIA driver. Try to boot into the previous kernel (via Grub).
If the problem is solved you may need to keep that kernel until a fixed NVIDIA driver arrives.
